# Remove space between dial in jQueryKnob.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, jquery-knob

I have the dial setup completely and as I am using it for selecting the direction based on a compass I have been stuck on a problem that is really weird to figure out.

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qeTzS.gif)

Comment: Can you explain what problem you are facing? In this demo what needs to be resolved?

Comment: @Soundar : Yes, in the gif you will be able to see there is space between the dial. I want to remove that as mentioned in the image and the question itself.

Comment: I can't understand which space you are speaking about. Are you mentioned the dragging step space?

Comment: @Soundar : yes the white space between two dial selection. i.e when I select 1 or 2, the space between them.

Comment: We are going to need some code to work with here. @Viral Patel